# Problems launching/debugging NativeScript app on iOS after recent OS and framework updates

Tags: ios, debugging, nativescript

I have two problems, probably technically unrelated, but related in the sense that I am blocked from continuing.  Since recent updates of NativeScript to 6.1.2 and IOS to 13.1.2 on my device I get only a blank screen when displaying a RadListView list that has previously worked, and continues to work on Android, as well as an iOS emulator, and an older iOS device (10.3.3).  What's more:  I find I can no longer install onto my 13.1.2 device with the tns CLI, and since I uninstalled the app in an attempt to get it to work, I'm completely blocked from debugging this problem further.

Any suggestions?

Before removing existing app, output would claim it had successfully installed a new image, but would fail to run it.  Running manually would not result in any console log output as I would expect.  Problem exhibits itself with no clues.  Finally, after uninstalling to try to remedy the problem, it now fails to do anything after "installing on device xxxxx....."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue with RadListView is known on iOS 13, there is a related [Github issue](https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-ui-feedback/issues/1160). You have to update the plugin to at least `v7.0.4` for it to work with iOS 13.

If you are using other UI plugins like RadSideDrawer, you may have to update to the latest version which is `7.1.0` as of today.

Comment: Thanks.  This gets be back in business on the list.  I'm still having trouble launching on my device, but I've learned it will eventually install still, so I can at least get it there.

Comment: Also: I discovered the problem with installing/launching was related to an Xcode auto-update that failed.  Manually upgrading Xcode solved the launch and console connection problems I was having.